# How to Toggle() Contents Vertically Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using `jQuery`'s `toggle()` to create a topnav for the mobile version of my site. By the clicking a button, a menu should be toggled from the top of the page, my code works but if you look carefully, it seems that the texts are disappearing horizontally instead of vertically. Is there a way to force the text to be toggled vertically too?

[js-fiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/0rd2juxc/10/)

```js
$(".button").click(function () {
  $(".item").toggle(300);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000000;
  /* font-weight: 300; */
}

.item {
  display: none;
  visibility: none;
}
 
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title> damn </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='menu'>
    <p class='item center' href='#'> item 1 </p>
    <p class='item center' href='#'> item 2 </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class='button'>
    <p class='center'>show menu</p>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: use `$('.item').toggle('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 300)`

Comment: happy coding mate

Comment: @lleiou unless you are using jQuery UI or jQuery 1.8 or older, `$('.item').toggle('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 300)` will not work, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808016/2813224).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

BTW, `<script>` tags either go inside the `<head>` tag or before the closing `</body>` tag. Also a `<p>` tag with a `[href]` attribute is invalid. An `<a>`, `<link>`, or `<base>` with a `[href]` attribute is valid.

The demo below has two buttons:

1. `$('.item').slideToggle(300);`
2. `$('.item').toggle('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 300);`

The second button will fail because the options:

```
  ('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 300);
```

is syntax for [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/), or jQuery 1.8 or earlier ([`.toggle(handler, handler, [handler])`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/#toggle-handler-handler-handler) was removed in jQuery 1.9).

---

### Demo

```js
$(".button1").click(function() {
  $('.item').slideToggle(300);
});

$(".button2").click(function() {
  $('.item').toggle('slide', {
    direction: 'down'
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 100 small-caps 14px/1.45 Arial;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: none;
}

code {
  font: 100 normal 10px/1.45 Consolas;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <nav class='menu'>
    <a class='item' href='#'>Item 1</a>
    <a class='item' href='#'>Item 2</a>
    <a class='item' href='#'>Item 3</a>
  </nav>

  <a class='button1' href="#/">1. <code>$('.item').slideToggle(300);</code></a>

  <a class='button2' href="#/">2. <code>$('.item').toggle('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 300);</code></a>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!